# Derivative determinant of Schur Complement

Tags: matrices, derivatives, determinant, schur-complement

I want to compute the derivative determinant of Schur Complement  $\frac{\partial}{\partial C}\det(C^*-P^*C^{-1}P)$ Where $C$ and $P$  are  $N\times N$ square symmetric complex matrices.

I am not getting a clue of it where to start, please provide me some hints!

I appreciate your suggestions

Comment: Perhaps a nice approach is to use some kind of implicit differentiation, noting that
$$
\det(C^* - P^*C^{-1}P) \det(C) = \det \pmatrix{C^* & P^* \\ P & C}
$$

Comment: deleted comment from the answerer: *I fell asleep at the wheel, [he is] correct, I forgot about the $\det C$ which adds to the complexity. I don't have time to fix it now, so will delete until I do.*

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I tried to do this way not sure if its right, let $$\underline(A)=\begin{bmatrix} C  & P \\ P^* & C^* \end{bmatrix}$$ Now determinant of this matrix is $\frac{\partial}{\partial C}\det (\underline{A})=\det(C)\det(C^*- P^*C^{-1}P)$. This now could be computed as  $$\det(C)(2C^{-1}-C^{-1}\circ I) \det(C^*- P^*C^{-1}P)+ \det(C) \frac{\partial}{\partial C}\det(C^*- P^*C^{-1}P)$$ Which is just equal to 
$$\det(C)(2C^{-1}-C^-1\circ I) \det(C^*- P^*C^{-1}P)+ \det(C) \det(C^*- P^*C^{-1}P)\left(2(C^*- P^*C^{-1}P)^{-1}-(C^*- P^*C^{-1}P)^{-1}\circ I \right)$$.